# How can i minimize the number of test expressions in if statements?

Tags: c, if-statement

So i have 4 variables that i need to check in order for my program to work, it gets to 16 test expressions in one if statement if hard coded. How could i minimize it ? The only way i thought of going was boolean algebra and i was very wrong. Anyone have any suggestions or something i would appreciate. The function is something like a printf function.

```
string = form("%d %s %f %lf %c", 1, "ASA", 4.12345, 1.123421, 'A');


char * form(char * format, ...){

char * result = (char *)calloc(1, 1), val_int[12], * val_str, * pos_int, * pos_str, val_double[12], * pos_double, * pos_char, * pos_float, val_float[12];
va_list arguments; va_start(arguments, format);

do
{
    pos_int = strstr(format, "%d"); pos_str = strstr(format, "%s"); pos_double = strstr(format, "%lf"); pos_float = strstr(format, "%f"); pos_char = strstr(format, "%c");

    if(pos_int && (pos_int < pos_str && pos_int < pos_float && pos_int < pos_double && pos_int < pos_char))
    {
        sprintf(val_int, "%d", va_arg(arguments, int));
        result = (char *)realloc(result, strlen(val_int) + strlen(result) + (pos_int - format) + 1);

        strncat(result, format, pos_int - format);
        strcat(result, val_int);
        format = pos_int + 2;
    }
    else if(pos_str && ( pos_str < pos_int && pos_str < pos_float && pos_str < pos_double && pos_str < pos_char))
    {
        val_str = va_arg(arguments, char *);
        result = (char *)realloc(result, strlen(val_str) + strlen(result) + (pos_str - format) + 1);

        strncat(result, format, pos_str - format);
        strcat(result, val_str);
        format = pos_str + 2;
    }
    else if(pos_double && (pos_double < pos_float && pos_double < pos_char && pos_double < pos_str && pos_double < pos_int))
    {
        sprintf(val_double, "%lf", va_arg(arguments, double));
            result = (char *)realloc(result, strlen(val_double) + strlen(result) + (pos_double - format) + 1);

        strncat(result, format, pos_double - format);
        strcat(result, val_double);                     
        format = pos_double + 3;
    }
    else if(pos_float && (pos_float < pos_int && pos_float < pos_double && pos_float < pos_str && pos_float < pos_char))
    {
        sprintf(val_float, "%f", (float)va_arg(arguments, double));
        result = (char *)realloc(result, strlen(val_float) + strlen(result) + (pos_float - format) + 1);

        strncat(result, format, pos_float - format);
        strcat(result, val_float);
        format = pos_float + 2;
    }
    else if(pos_char && (pos_char < pos_int && pos_char < pos_str && pos_char < pos_float && pos_char < pos_double))
    {
        char val_char[2] = "\0";
        val_char[0] = (char)va_arg(arguments, int);
        result = (char *)realloc(result, strlen(val_float) + strlen(result) + (pos_float - format) + 1);

        strncat(result, format, pos_float - format);
        strcat(result, val_float);
        format = pos_float + 2;
    }
}while(pos_int || pos_str || pos_double || pos_float || pos_char);

va_end(arguments);

result = (char *)realloc(result, strlen(result) + strlen(format) + 1);
strcat(result, format);
return result; }
```

In these if statements is only one test expression besides the first which just sees if the main variable for the testing is initialized, and i need to do another 15 for making every possible situation for each if statement.

Comment: The only way to shorten *any* expression checking is by writing methods to do it or find a different way to do the same checks.

Comment: Your logic seems to be flawed.  If, for example, `pos_str` is NULL then none of the if conditions will be true (because `pointer_variable < NULL` is undefined behavior, and will typically always false because the comparison is often an unsigned comparison with 0).

Comment: You have 5 test expressions not 16 in any one `if` statement, and 5 `if` tests. Line 11 has 5 statements on the same line. Some of the individual tests are repeated, and `strlen` is called with the same argument several times.  It isn't very clear what is being asked, why don't you precalculate some of those things and simplify the test expressions.

Comment: @HunterL Thanks for the reply do you think it is possible to minimize it to a certain point by implementing boolean algebra ? For example !pos_int = !A , pos_int < pos_str = A.

Comment: What is to stop you from doing that if you feel it is simpler on the eye?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yeah i know that, that is what i am saying about being to much expressions. Thats only the one and 15 more are missing like (!pos_str && !pos_float && !pos_double && !pos_char) || (!pos_str && !pos_float && !pos_double && pos_int < pos_char) ...

Comment: What this code is supposed to do? Can you please properly indent your code and not separate expressions with comma operator and put separate statements on separate lines?  Are you reimplementing `asprintf`? Why aren't you just `int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, va);  char*buf = malloc(len); va_copy(...); vsprintf(buf, format, va2)` ?

Comment: The correct way to do this is `strchr(format, '%')`, and then `switch` on the character after the `%`. BTW, as far as `printf` is concerned, `%f` and `%lf` are exactly the same.

Comment: @WeatherVane 1.) The first test expression just checks that the variable that is crucial to that line is set, and the others are just to check its placing in the string. 2.) Did you mean about boolean algebra or ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @KamilCuk The code is meant to print format specifiers to equal data types. Sorry for those separate lines i thought it would be easier to read. The variables with pos_... mean the position of the format specifier in the string and val_... mean the value which is given from them using va_arg

Comment: `The code is meant to print format specifiers to equal data types` I do not understand that. So `form("%s", "1")` should _print_ `%s`? It looks like your function allocates memory and returns it - it doesn't print anything. It really looks like `asprintf`. I believe the code would be simpler, if you would first just find only `%`, then inspect the next character after `%` and  make a decision.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you for that insight ill try to do it with the switch, as for %f and %lf being the same i know but this is just some homework that the professor suggested us.

Comment: @KamilCuk It should print out variables to the correct format specifier that is used in the function form. For example: form("I have %d %s and sliced them in %f , apple starts with %c", 2 , "apples", 0.5, 'A'); Something like that and no it does print when you hard code 16 test expressions into 5 if statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we try to use your general structure, this can be made simpler by a `struct` table/array with one element for each data type.

**However**, doing *repeated* `strstr` is a bit wasteful and having all the `pos_*` variables et. al. is needlessly complicated.

The usual, simpler, and *faster* method is to scan the format string char-by-char and find the *next* format specifier (e.g. `%d` or `%f`) and then do a `switch` on type.

Also, each type was doing its own `realloc/strcat/strncat`. Better to add a helper function or two to maintain a buffer/length along with a `struct` for append control.

At first, I tried to merely clean up your code a bit. But, I soon realized that the only thing that made sense was to heavily refactor it.

This works. It could use a bit more error/underflow/overflow checking. And, is simpler and [again] *faster*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

struct out {
    int len;
    char *buf;
};

static void
append_str(struct out *out,const char *str,int ilen)
{
    int olen;

    if (ilen < 0)
        ilen = strlen(str);

    out->buf = realloc(out->buf,out->len + ilen + 1);
    memcpy(&out->buf[out->len],str,ilen);

    out->len += ilen;
    out->buf[out->len] = 0;
}

static void
append_char(struct out *out,int chr)
{
    char str[2];

    str[0] = chr;
    str[1] = 0;

    append_str(out,str,1);
}

char *
form(char *format, ...)
{
    struct out out;
    char tmp[100];
    int chr;
    va_list arguments;
    int ilen;
    char *cp;

    va_start(arguments, format);

    out.buf = NULL;
    out.len = 0;

    while (*format != 0) {
        chr = *format++;

        // ordinary char
        if (chr != '%') {
            append_char(&out,chr);
            continue;
        }

        // grab format specifier
        int lflg = 0;
        while (*format != 0) {
            chr = *format++;
            if (chr != 'l')
                break;
            lflg = 1;
        }

        if (chr == '%') {
            append_char(&out,chr);
            continue;
        }

        ilen = -1;
        switch (chr) {
        case 'd':
            ilen = sprintf(tmp, "%d", va_arg(arguments, int));
            break;

        case 'f':
            if (lflg)
                ilen = sprintf(tmp, "%lf", va_arg(arguments, double));
            else
                ilen = sprintf(tmp, "%f", va_arg(arguments, double));
            break;

        case 'c':
            chr = va_arg(arguments,int);
            append_char(&out,chr);
            break;

        case 's':
            cp = va_arg(arguments, char *);
            append_str(&out,cp,-1);
            break;

        default:
            exit(1);
            break;
        }

        if (ilen > 0)
            append_str(&out,tmp,ilen);
    }

    va_end(arguments);

    return out.buf;
}

int
main(void)
{
    char *string;

    string = form("%d %s %f %lf %c", 1, "ASA", 4.12345, 1.123421, 'A');
    printf("%s\n",string);
    free(string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time and simplifying my code. I really should have used the switch statement.

Comment: Not to worry. I have a lot of experience [more years than I'm willing to admit to in polite company :-)]. I've had to fit code into an FPGA that had only 128KB of memory. I could _not_ fit the standard `printf` into that space, so I had to roll my own that _could_ fit. So, I've done several [approx five] implementations of `printf` for realtime systems, so,  my reasoning was: "Hey, I've done this before. It would be disingenuous to not post some of the benefits of that". The maxim is [don't take this personally, as I apply it to myself on a daily basis]: _Don't tweak bad code--rewrite it_